# n+k patterns in F#?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I wrote the following in F#:

```
let fib x = 
  match x with
  | 0 -> 0
  | 1 -> 1
  | n+2 -> fib n + fib (n+1)
```

Unfortunately, I got a compiler error stating I had used an infix operator in an unexpected place. Other than using the wildcard character, is there a way I can express my intent in F#?

Comment: I'm not a Haskeller, but I've heard that `n+k` patterns should be avoided if possible (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_programming_tips/Discussion#n.2Bk_patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# doesn't support [n+k patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK), but you can rewrite it in terms of just *n*:

```
let rec fib x =
    match x with
    | 0 -> 0
    | 1 -> 1
    | n -> fib (n - 2) + fib (n - 1)
```

Note that recursive functions in F# need the `rec` keyword, unlike in Haskell.

Comment: I have to get faster in posting my answers :)

Answer (score 6):

You can get that by definining an active pattern. I'm not exactly sure how n+k patterns work with Haskell (e.g. can they ever fail?), but the following should be a good start:

```
// Result of matching 'input' against 'add + k'
let (|PlusNum|) add input = 
  input - add

let rec fib = function
  | 0 -> 0 
  | 1 -> 1 
  | PlusNum 2 n -> fib n + fib (n+1)
```

EDIT: Based on the comment by sepp2k, here is an updated version that fails if "n" would be negative:

```
// Result of matching 'input' against 'add + k'
let (|PlusNum|_|) add input = 
  if input - add < 0 then None 
  else Some(input - add)
```

Comment: Yes, they can fail in Haskell. Specifically they don't match if `n` would be negative.

Comment: @sepp2k: Hmm.. so does that mean that "n" will always be positive? That's interesting (I would expect that it can be negative too). It is good that feature like this isn't built into the F# language and you can make design decisions yourself :-)

Comment: It can also be 0. But not negative. Note that you're not the only person who finds that odd and that n+k patterns no longer exist in Haskell 2010.

Comment: A functional way of describing natural numbers (0+) is by `Zero` and `Succ(x)`. In this system, the pattern `n-2` is interpreted as `Succ(Succ(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

I would subtract -2 on both sides.
And you have to add the rec keyword, because you are declaring a recursive function.

so you get:

```
let rec fib x =
    match x with
    | 0 -> 0
    | 1 -> 1
    | n -> fib (n - 2) + fib (n - 1)
```